# WebDynpro ABAP Application Development Issue

Tags: abap, sap-gui, webdynpro

I am trying to develop WebDynpro Abap, but I am facing the following error,

[image: error Image]

Can anyone advise me how to resolve this issue, or I am missing any authorizations.

Thanks,
Eliza

Comment: Hi, Eliza according to the script error you are trying to access the style property from a variable that is referring to nothing at line 528.if still need help comment below!

Comment: @Achuthhadnoor, Cap?:)

Comment: @Eliza, what are you doing at the moment when error is thrown? UIElementContainer doesn't have *Style* property, so it seems to be another thing.

Comment: @Achuth I am missing the style property, but how should I remove this error? can u suggest.
Thanks,
Eliza

Comment: @Suncatcher, I am trying to make a simple dynpro app, what I am doing is as I m dropping a control from solution explorer in the layout, its throwing script error. That can be seen in the attached image above.
Can u guide me how to add style property, I still feel issue is related to some network kind of error.
Thanks,
Eliza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your GUI from the market place, to Version 740.

Regards,
Hamdan